# <!--[If IE]> Not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- [If IE]><script>alert('IE!')</script><![endif] -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello World
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there something wrong with this, or do I need to add a DOCtype / meta heading to get it to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just to clarify (since noone has really).

It's the space between `<!--` and `[If IE]` aswell as the space after `[endif]` that breaks your code. It's not there in any of the answers that are previous to mine, therefor they work and yours do not.

Bad:

```html
<!-- [If IE]> <![endif] -->
```

Good:

```html
<!--[If IE]> <![endif]-->
```

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is a good practice, but not needed for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <!--[if IE]><script src="global.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need the `type` attribute if you use the HTML 5 doctype.